# Removing header region

Tags: 7, theming

I am completely new to drupal. I am trying to customize the Acquia Marina theme to suit my upcoming site. The original layout is as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Screen Shot:]

I want to remove the white band that is the header region and move the logo and title down to the blue band right below it. Basically, have the blue strip function as the header. Is that possible. I have tried removing the `header` and `header-top` regions from the info file but that did not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the html structure for this. Open page.tpl.php then remove the header section from there.